# using php to dynamically populate the string.xml file in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, xml

how can I get the ChatList names from the database and populate them in strings.xml file string array tag using php and mysql

```
   <string-array name="chatListNames">
            <item>Byamukama Robinhood</item>
            <item>Test name</item>
            <item>Ivan</item>
            <item>Mohsin Afir</item>
            <item>Test</item>

    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> populate them in strings.xml file string array tag using php and mysql

`strings.xml` *are for constant(read-only) strings so it's not possible to change at runtime*

So instead of adding strings in `strings.xml` which want to change at runtime save in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

> how can I get the ChatList names from the database

Use web-services for getting ChatList names from server  in application then update all values in `SharedPreferences`.

See following good tutorial for creating web-services in PHP and accessing from Android:

[How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: using this code , how can call php script  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
  /* Loads (names,lastSeen,images) From Resources
   * Here you can load it from a Web Server
   * */
  names   = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chatListNames);
  lastSeen  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.usersLastSeen);
  images   = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chatListImages);

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Android, you can use a database to do that. Strings.xml is can not be modified at run time.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code and change db name and access, run it in browser and copy paste the same to XML file.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<string-array name="chatListNames">";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<item>" . $row["id"]. "</item><br>";
    }
    echo "</string-array>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```